# Problems with dynamic memory allocation in class

Tags: c++, class, c++11, dynamic-memory-allocation, freeze

I am trying to create a class for a pizza restaurant where i have both a separate class for the `Pizza` and another for the restaurant. The restaurant class has a dynamic array of type `Pizza` whose size increases everytime another pizza is added to the restaurant.

Whenever i execute the program it stops working in the for loop before a new object is created and the `addPizza()` function is called without giving an error or absolutely anything. I am still new to programming so i think i may be allocating the memory incorrectly thus causing it to freeze. Can anyone please help me on as to what i am doing wrong ?

Thank you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Pizza {
private:
    char name[15];
    int price;
    char *ingredients;
    int reduction;
public:
    Pizza (char  *name= "", int price= 0, char *ingredients= "", int reduction= 0) {
        this->ingredients= new char [strlen(ingredients)+1];
        strcpy(this->ingredients, ingredients);
        strcpy(this->name, name);
        this->price= price;
        this->reduction= reduction;
    }
    ~Pizza () {
        delete [] ingredients;
    }
    bool areSame(Pizza p) {
        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(this->ingredients) + 1; i++) 
            if (this->ingredients[i] != p.ingredients[i])
                return true;
        return false;            
    }

    int getReduction() {
        return reduction;
    }

    void print() {
        cout << "name: " << name<< " ingredients: " << ingredients<< " Price: " << price;
    }
};

class Pizzeria{
private:
    char name[15];
    Pizza *p;
    int number_of_pizzas;
public:
    Pizzeria(char *name= "") {  
        strcpy(this->name, name);
        p = new Pizza [0];
        number_of_pizzas = 1;
    }

    Pizzeria(const Pizzeria &x) {
        this->p = new Pizza [x.number_of_pizzas-1];
        for (int i = 0; i < number_of_pizzas; i++) {
            this->p[i] = x.p[i];
        }
        this->number_of_pizzas= x.number_of_pizzas;
        strcpy(this->name, x.name);
    }   

    ~Pizzeria() {
        delete [] p;
    }

    void addPizza(Pizza P) {cout<<"fsfas";
        for (int i = 0; i < number_of_pizzas; i++) {
            if (!(p[i].areSame(P))) {
                number_of_pizzas++;
                p[number_of_pizzas] = P;
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    void pizzasOnPromotion() {
        for (int i = 0; i < number_of_pizzas; i++)
            if (p->getReduction() > 0)
                p->print();
    }

    void setName(char *name) {
        strcpy(this->name, name);
    }
    char getName() {
        return *name;
    }
};

int main () {

int n;
char name[15]; 
Pizzeria p1(name);
cin >> name;
cin >> n;
int reduc;

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    char imp[100];
    cin.get();
    cin.getline(imp,100);
    int price;
    cin >> price;
    char ingredients[100];
    cin.get();
    cin.getline(ingredients,100);
    cin >> reduc;   cout << "pls work";
    Pizza p(imp,price,ingredients,reduc);

    p1.addPizza(p);
}

Pizzeria p2 = p1;
cin >> name;
p2.setName(name);
char imp[100];
cin.get();
cin.getline(imp,100);
int price;
cin >> price;
char ingredients[100];
cin.get();
cin.getline(ingredients,100);
cin >> reduc;
Pizza p(imp,price,ingredients,reduc);
p2.addPizza(p);

cout<<p1.getName()<<endl;
cout<<"Pizzas on promotion:"<<endl;
p1.pizzasOnPromotion();

cout<<p2.getName()<<endl;
cout<<"Pizzas on promotion:"<<endl;
p2.pizzasOnPromotion();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger at all?

Comment: I dont know how to use one yet. Like i said i completely new to programming.

Comment: 1) If you tried stepping through your code with a debugger, you wouldn't need to speculate on what/where the problem is. You would know that. 2) "_I dont know how to use one yet_"  So, what's stopping you from learning that?

Comment: I figured you were completely new - and that's why I indicated that the real solution to this and the many other such situations you will face is to learn, as soon as possible, how to debug problems for yourself, instead of asking people on the internet to figure it out for you. You know your code, you have your code, and you can debug your code; other people have a severe disadvantage, and asking them on every setback will waste a lot of time on both sides.

Comment: The root of the dynamic memory allocation is that you are using `char` arrays or pointers to C-Style strings.  Use `std::string`, so you don't need to bother with dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: How to debug small programs : https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: You wrote too much. The right question you should pose is: "how do I install and run a C++ debugger?"

Answer (score 1):

Not sure that is your problem but is a (big!) problem.

Your `class Pizza` dinamically allocate memory in constructor

```
this->ingredients= new char [strlen(ingredients)+1];
```

but is without (a) copy contructor, (b) move constructor, (c) `operator=(Pizza const &)` and (d) `operator=(Pizza &&)`.

This guarantee you problems; big problems.

And a point that can give you problems is `class Pizzeria` (en passant: another class with dynamic memory allocation, a decent copy constructor but without (a) move constructor, (b) `operator=(Pizzeria const &)` and (d) `operator=(Pizzeria &&)`) where, in copy constructor, you have

```
this->p[i] = x.p[i];
```

After this instruction (that call the implicit `operator=(Pizza const &)`) you have `this->p[i]` and `x.p[i]` with the same value for `ingredients`.

No problem when is called the destructor of the first one. But when is called the destructor of the second one, you have a double free over the same allocated value that is undefined behavior but often crash the program.

Some suggestions.

You tagged C++11, so you can use smart pointers (`std::unique_ptr`, `std::shared_ptr`).

Avoid, when possible, the direct managing of dynamically allocated memory and use `std::string`'s and STL containers (by example: a `std::string` for `ingredients` and a `std::vector<Pizza>` for `Pizza` in `class Pizzeria`).

When it's impossible avoid the managing of dynamically allocated memory, use smart pointers.

When you're forced (but really forced) to directly use `new` and `delete`, ever remember copy and move contructors and `operator=()`'s

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what exactly you wanna do with your second class, but you can rewrite your first one as follows, then half of the headache is away.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Pizza
{
private:
    string name;
    int price;
    int reduction;
    string ingredients;
public:
    Pizza (const string& name, const int& price, const int& reduction,
           const string& ingredients)
        :name(name), price(price), reduction(reduction), ingredients(ingredients)
        {}
    ~Pizza () {}

    bool areSame(const Pizza& p)const
    {   return this->ingredients == p.ingredients;     }

    const int& getReduction()const {    return reduction;}

    void print()
    {
        cout << "name: " << name<< " ingredients: " << ingredients<< " Price: " << price;
    }
};
```

if you can explain your second class ideas, may be I can help.

The second class should start something like follows(Note that I have changes `char*` to `std::string` which is easier to think:

```
class Pizzeria
{
private:
    string name;
    int number_of_pizzas;
    Pizza *p;
public:
    Pizzeria() = default;

    Pizzeria(const string& name)
        :name(name), number_of_pizzas(0), p(nullptr)    {}

    Pizzeria(const string& name, const int& number, Pizza *p)
        :name(name), number_of_pizzas(number), p(p)     {}

    // hope, you wanted a copy constructor here.
    Pizzeria(const Pizzeria &x)
        :name(x.name), number_of_pizzas(x.number_of_pizzas)
    {
        this->p = new Pizza(*x.p);
    }

    ~Pizzeria() {   delete[] p;    }

    void addPizza(Pizza P)
    {
       //explain the concept
    }

    void pizzasOnPromotion()
    {
        //explain the concept
    }

    void setName(const string& name) {  this->name = name;  }
    const string& getName()const  { return name;    }
};
```